# Something wrong with pointer accessing?

Tags: c, pointers

I hope I have not oversimplified my code, but what I am basically trying to do is to find the existence of an element in a container, and return the pointer to it.

I have structures like

```
typedef struct INHs{
    int ID;
} INHs;

typedef struct sub_container{
    INHs** list_inh;
    int nb_list;
} sub_container;

typedef struct container {
    sub_container* cont;
    int nb_elem;
} container;
```

And then in my main method I have a container allocated (I will leave it out for simplicity, and a given ID; and for now I won't to iterate over the sub-containers to find my target INHs structure).

```
INHs** test_INH = NULL;
INHs** return_val = NULL;

int ID = 10;

container* cont; //allocated on all memory 

for (uint n=0; !test_INH && n<container_nb_elem; n++){

    return_val = find_ptr(&cont[n], ID, &test_INH);

}


INHs** find_ptr(sub_container* sub_cont, int ID, INHs*** test){

    INHs** res = NULL;

    for (uint i=0; !res && i<sub_cont->nb_list; i++){

      if (sub_cont->list_inh[i].ID == ID) {

         (*test) = &(sub_cont->list_inh[i]);
         res = &(sub_cont->list_inh[i]);
      }

    return res;
}
```

I know I don't need both  a return value to my element and another one as a function parameter, but these are the two versions I have tried. I don't know what I am doing wrong but valgrind crashes telling me that either "test_INH" or "result_val" are non-initialized, although I am setting them on null.

Does someone see what I am missing here?

Comment: i think it may be relevant to see how you allocated your structures

Comment: Maybe show us the exact error.

Comment: Note: C does not support _methods_. And you should use a debugger.

Comment: Hey, a *three star programmer* Note: you dont *need* the `***test` argument. (it is basically the same as the return value) And: you could jump out of your loops (even `return`) once the element is found.

Comment: Thank you Olaf for your helpful comment, what do you think Valgrind is? 

And I know i dont need to use ***test, as I have stated in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct INHs{
    int id;
} INHs;

typedef struct sub_container{
    INHs **ptrs;
    int nb_list;
} sub_container;

typedef struct container {
    sub_container *items;
    int nb_elem;
} container;

int main(void)
{
INHs **found = NULL;
int id = 10;
container *cont; //allocated on all memory 

for (uint n=0; n < cont->nb_elem; n++){
    found = find_ptr( &cont->items[n], id);
    if (found) break; /* found it! */
    }

if(found) {
        /* do something useful with *found ... */
        }
return 0;
}

INHs **find_ptr(sub_container *sub_cont, int id)
{

for (uint i=0; i < sub_cont->nb_list; i++){
    if (sub_cont->ptrs[i]->id != id) continue;
    return &sub_cont->ptrs[i];
    }

return NULL;
}
```

---

BTW: I find the array of pointers to **one `integer`** structures rather strange.
Are these structures all malloc()d separately?

Comment: It's likely (or, at least we can pretend that it is) that the 1-integer structure is an artefact of the MCVE-creation process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed. It could indeed be some heterogenous set of items. Or pointers into other structures.